# 'Remote Registry (RemoteRegistry)' cannot be started

Tags: powershell

I have been receiving a RemoteRegistry error and I am wondering how to fix this. I have tried shortening my code to one line to even just start the service but for some reason I keep receiving this error:

```
Start-Service : Service 'Remote Registry (RemoteRegistry)' cannot be started due
to the following error: Cannot open RemoteRegistry service on computer 'IT-Tech'.
At line:1 char:59
+ Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName IT-Tech | Start-Service
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Code:

```
Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName IT-Tech | Start-Service
```

I just don't understand why I keep getting

> Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'remoteregistry'.

Comment: Verify that the Windows Firewall allows connections to the remote host, and that your account has admin privileges on that host.

Comment: have admin rights but cant figure out how to verify the firewall

Comment: By checking the Windows Firewall settings on the remote host, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

The RemoteRegistry is disabled by default.  This can be seen using:

```
Get-Service RemoteRegistry | Select-Object StartType
```

To enable it, the Set-Service command can be used:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName <Remote Computer> -Name RemoteRegistry | Set-Service -StartupType Manual -PassThru| Start-Service
```

To disable again:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName <Remote Computer> -Name RemoteRegistry | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -PassThru| Stop-Service
```